# How to Update customer in magento 2.2 programmatically?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-account

I want to update customer information programmatically. so I have used below code.

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
try{
    $path = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('catalog/import/epicore/UPB-customers.csv');
    $dataExcel = fopen($path, "r");
    while (!feof($dataExcel) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($dataExcel, 1024);
    }
    array_shift($line_of_text); 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    foreach($line_of_text as $customerNewData){
        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($customerNewData[0]);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($customer->getData()); exit;            
        if(count($customer)){
            $data = array(); 
            $email = $customer->getEmail();             
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->setData("custid", $customerNewData[1]);
            $customer->setData("custnum", $customerNewData[2]);
            $customer->setData("salesforceid", $customerNewData[3]);
            $customer->setEmail($email);                
            $customer->save();
        }else{

        }   
    }           
} catch(\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); exit;
}
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
}
```

But Its returns "Please enter email address" error.

Comment: Please check email is getting from customer or not. after that set it in customer. **@Ajay**

Comment: it i am checking full object and email address alreadt preset here. @DhadukMitesh

Comment: Then check you add all require field or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use service contracts instead of Model Class (and strictly don't use object manager)

```
protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    ------------------
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    -----------------
)
{
    ------------
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    -----------
}

public function {myFunction}(){

    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerNewData[0]);

    if($customer->getId())
    {
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->setCustid($customerNewData[1]);
            $customer->setCustnum($customerNewData[2]);
            $customer->setSalesforceid($customerNewData[3]);
            $customer->setEmail($email);
    }
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer)  ;
}
```

Comment: I have already try this but getting save($customer); undefined function.

Comment: @AjayPatel How could this be undefined. Please double check for any typo or post your class code.

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: @AjayPatel `$customer->save();` is wrong. You need to use `$objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->save($customer)` instead.

Comment: can you know how to update my custom created attribute and show in magento 2.2 admin panel in customer grid or customer data part?

Comment: @AjayPatel You should ask a separate question for attribute thing and explain there.